# Reference UIButton by Tag

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton

How can I reference by code a button's tag value which I assigned earlier?

What I'm trying to do is create a list in a table view that has checkbox images in each row. I only want one to be selected at a time within each section, so once one is selected, I would loop through the other buttons to unselect the others.

Below is the code how I assign each button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UIButton *addCheckButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
addCheckButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 40.0f, 5.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);  
[addCheckButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_empty.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[addCheckButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_full.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[cell addSubview:addCheckButton];
[addCheckButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeCheckState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
addCheckButton.tag = ([indexPath section] + 1) * 100 + [indexPath row];
```

I then can strip out the section and row of the selected button in my table view in the `changeCheckState` IBAction.

But I would also like something that I can say "**Deselect buttons with tag 101, 102 and 103**" within `changeCheckState`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
id my101Button = [view viewWithTag:101];
```

This question is one of those that are googled in seconds.